# Difference between "Redmine on Heroku" and "Installing Redmine" documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My intention is to install Redmine on Heroku.

On redmine.org, there are two docs that I came across:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Heroku.

I know the second doc is self-explanatory in its title but I want to know if I follow the first doc's instructions, would I be able to still deploy Redmine to Heroku. OR is it better that I follow the second doc's instructions?

A noob at this, any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

==============

Following the Heroku specific instructions (step 5), I tried to run rake generate_secret_token using Ruby's CMD however I get back 'Please configure your config/database.yml first'. There are two related files in two different locations. C:\Users\\redmine\config AND from C:\Users\\Desktop\\redmine-2.5.1\config. Which database.yml do I use? The config file on the second path has only database.yml.example. Do I make the change there and save it as 'database.yml'? Or do I make the change in the first location, cd to the first location and run rake generate_secret_token?

Comment: I can’t tell you which directory to use, I don’t know why you have two of them. You should be configuring inside the directory that you ran `git clone` on. Presumably it’s the `redmine-2.5.1` one, since the Heroku instructions for Redmine say you should copy the `.example` file before modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Heroku-specific instructions. The first document explains how to install Redmine on a server that you have full (`root`) control over. It entails logging into the machine and running various commands to install software.

Heroku does not give you a full server instance in the way the first document requires. Instead, you work on your application on your own machine and push it from there to Heroku. Things like database setup are configured through Heroku addons. You do not get access to the filesystem, which is in fact read-only.

The first document wouldn’t work for installing on Heroku.

Comment: Hi Buck, thanks your for the response. I don't have a server to work with and I am just installing it on my local computer... which should still work on my local computer correct? To confirm my understanding of your response, I need to follow the first doc and then deploy it to Heroku? When I deploy the app to Heroku, I would then need to follow the instructions on Heroku's site?

Comment: Yes, using the Heroku instructions, you can download Redmine locally and push it from there to Heroku. The instructions tell you how to deploy to Heroku, but you’ll need to have a Heroku account and be set up to run Heroku commands, which you can do by [following the Getting Started with Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart).

Comment: I thought I was headed in the wrong direction when I got to step 5 on the Heroku-specific instructions so it was why I posed the original question. Would you be able to provide some feedback to my second part of the question? I had installed postgresql but the cmd keeps saying I need gem install mysql2.. which isn't still working when I am installing it from ruby gem site. Does that mean I need to install MySQL or am I supposed to comment out the mysql sections in the database.yml file?